# About marquee tag usage instead of j query

Tags: jquery, html

I likes to use marquee tag in my web project, Is it is good practice using marquee than using j query ?
If using marquee as good practice or bad practice , explain me why?

Answer (score 1):

The Marquee feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.

JQuery is a well known standard and apart from the benefits of just learning to use this it is more powerful and you will find the ability to eventually do more with your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... i got idea to use j query in my page.

Answer (score 1):

The [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) about marquee:

> This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers,
>   its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to
>   avoid using it.

So the usuage of marquee will not be considered a good practice since its now discouraged and obsolete. You can try to avoid it.

As far as Jquery is concerned than it has many features and advantages. Its difficult to compare both of them.(*You are trying to compare two different things.*) Jquery is a language whereas marquee is just a feature/functionality.

Comment: Thanks for reply and i agree with your answer